# Nested For loop counter reset

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, nested-loops

I'm trying to run nested for loops that use lists as their loop counters. The problem is that once the 'delta' loop reaches 100, it doesnt reset to 0. Same problem for 'edges'.

I tried this, but it doesnt seem to work for my loops.
http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/nestedloops.html

Any ideas here? Here's my code:

```
#!/bin/sh

threads="1 2 4 8 16 32 64 96 128 160 192 224 256"
delta="0 10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 100"
edges="16 8192"
nodes="16384"

for threads in $threads
do
    for delta in $delta
    do
        for edges in $edges
        do
            for nodes in $nodes
            do
                printf "\n"
                echo $threads
                echo $delta
                echo $edges
                echo $nodes
            done
        done
    done
done
```

expected output:

```
1 0 16 16384 
1 0 8192 16384 
1 10 16 16384 
1 10 8192 16384 
1 20 16 16384 
1 20 8192 16384
```

Comment: If this is your *expected* output, then the script is correct, because that's what it outputs right now.

Comment: I want the inner loops to start from 0 again (from the first element of their list), once the outer loops do each iteration

Comment: Okay, I get it now that we have the expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `for` loops like this, make sure you give the loop variable a different name than the variable you are iterating over.

Using `for threads in $threads` makes it confusing to distinguish between the looping variable (`threads`) and the thing you're looping over (`$threads`).

When you call `echo $threads` later, bash doesn't know you're referring to the first one.

In this case, you could change the loop declarations to something like `for n in nodes` or `for t in threads`, then `echo` out `$n` and `$t` inside the innermost loop to obtain the desired output.

Comment: I cant see how that changes it. 

I need 13*10*2*1 iterations. Doing for n in nodes, and then echoing $n  doesnt reset the loop counter to 0...

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "reset the loop counter to 0". Making those changes gives the expected output on my system, however.

Comment: you can picture it like this:
each of the for loop should be like this
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
      for(j=0;j<10;j++)

now if I run the script in C like this, then the j loop would start from 0 on each iteration of the outer loop. I want this in this script :)

Comment: Okay, I get it. Is [this the output you're looking for?](http://pastebin.com/BnRRPkbY)

Comment: Ok, the changes I suggested in my answer gave me this output! If there is something you still do not understand, just let me know `:)`